# Is there a way to convert 3 layer network to 2 layer network with specific math formula?

Tags: neural-networks

Currently, my professor asked me to find an explicit formula to convert 3 layer network to 2 layer network. I've read some paper about the general properties of neural network, how its complexity is related to depth and width, but I haven't found a single paper talking about the conversion of network with different depths. Is there any paper related to this subject?

Comment: They could be expecting you to use distillation. That would be to train the smaller network to make the same predictions as the larger network.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that in the general case there is a way to convert a 3 layer network in a 2 layer network in an exact/closed form way

Then, given a $N$ layer network, considering the first $N-3$ layers as just a mere preprocessing, you can squeeze the last $3$ in $2$ layer, thus having a final network of $N-1$ layers

Now, rinse and repeat, and you have magically transformed a $N$ layers network in a $2$ layers network

Clearly there isn't such a way, mainly due to the non linearity in between layers (in the linear case, you might be able to do so, but you have not given any specification/hypothesis on the layers structure)

Having said this, there are ways to approximate this, indeed a $3$ layer network is still a function, and thus you can use a $2$ layers function approximator to approximate it, and this is usually called distillation, as [@David](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/36821/david) pointed out in the comments, however this is everything but guaranteed to converge (if you don't sample enough points, and if the smaller network has not enough capacity)